# Time-evolution of a matrix of vector fields: well-defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, smooth-manifolds, boundary-value-problem

Consider a $2 \times 2$ matrix of smooth vector fields on a smooth manifold $M$:
$$X = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
X_{11} & X_{12} \\
X_{22} & X_{21} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$
I'm thinking about $X$ as an operator on $C^\infty(M)^2$ or, if you prefer, as an operator on the sections of the trivial vector bundle $M \times \mathbb{R}^2$.

**Note:** It is fine with me if you want to replace $M$ by $\mathbb{R}^n$, I am mostly just trying to notationally distinguish it from the time dimension.

Suppose we want to talk about the associated time-evolution operators $e^{tX}: C^\infty(M)^2 \to C^\infty(M)^2$. What do we mean by that? Maybe it would be cleaner to talk instead about the following system of PDEs
\begin{align*}
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}u_1(t,x) &=  X_{11}u_1(t,x)  + X_{12} u_2(t,x) \\
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}u_2(t,x) &= X_{21}u_1(t,x)  + X_{22} u_2(t,x)
\end{align*}
where $u_1,u_2 \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}\times M)$ with the $X_{ij}$ acting in the obvious way along the fibers $\{t\}\times M$. Writing $u_t(x)=(u_1(t,x),u_2(t,x))$, the idea is then that $e^{tX} u_0 = u_t$.

Now, there is a pretty clear issue with existence. For example, if $M=\mathbb{R}$ with variable $x$ and
$$ X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$
then we are basically looking at the Cauchy Riemann equations and it will only make sense to apply $e^{tX}$ to $u_0 \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})^2$ if $u_0$ is the restriction to $\mathbb{R}$ of a holomorphic function.

Well OK fine. So $e^{tX}$ may only be defined on some domain in $C^\infty(M)^2$. We can live with that. There is also, however, the issue of uniqueness to contend with. It does not make sense to talk about the operators $e^{tX}$ unless the answer to the following question is "yes":

**Question:** Suppose $u_1$ and $u_2$ are smooth, real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R} \times M$ which satisfy
\begin{align*}
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}u_1(t,x) &=  X_{11}u_1(t,x)  + X_{12} u_2(t,x) \\
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}u_2(t,x) &= X_{21}u_1(t,x)  + X_{22} u_2(t,x).
\end{align*}
If $u_1$ and $u_2$ both vanish on $\{0\} \times M$, does it follow that $u_1=u_2=0$ everywhere?

**Comment:**

This is clearly a special case of a more general PDE uniqueness question, but I am not much versed in that subject. For example, suppose $Y$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix of smooth vector fields on a smooth manifold $N$ (above $N=\mathbb{R}\times N$), and $w \in C^\infty(N)^2$ belongs to the kernel of $Y$. If $w$ vanishes on a some hyper surface in $N$, does it follow that $w$ vanishes on all of $N$? The answer to this question is clearly "no", because we can take $Y=0$ and then every $w \in C^\infty(N)^2$ will be a solution. So, we need some assumptions about the behaviour of $Y$ near the hypersurface. A good guess is that this should all be related to ellipticity somehow, but are such strong assumptions really necessary to get uniqueness? Or am I missing some more obvious arguments?

Comment: The system of equations from the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem, given sufficient Cauchy conditions suggests that, depending on the form of the operator, it may exist. For example, in the case of the matrix defined in terms of a single x-derivative there is a unique solution. If you were presented with a matrix whose elements were functions of t for example as in the case of an ODE, then you can refer to the typical ODE existence theorems. As it's written, equations of the form $\partial_t u = F(x,u,u_x,...,u_{x...x})$ are well studied evolution equations. I would look into that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't want to make assumptions about analyticity so Cauchy-Kovalevskaya may not help much. I'm not much concerned with existence, just uniqueness. Regarding your last two sentences, I'm guess I'm basically looking at a situation like $\partial_t u = F(x,y,u_x,u_y)$ with $F$ being linear in $u_x$ and $u_y$, but nonlinear in $x,y$. Any suggestions for that specific case? Or even the case $u_t = f(x) u_x$, going down one dimension?

Comment: For non-analytic solutions, it may help to look into some of the methods of Cartan and the subject of Exterior Differential Systems. Convert these equations to differential forms (there are a variety of ways), and then utilize some of the existence theorems for the existence of integral manifolds. Also, make sure to look into some of the literature for Evolution Equations. There is a wealth of research there. For $u_t=f(x) u_x$, try considering the method of characteristics for a first order scalar pde.

Comment: @DogeChan: I see why the method of characteristics would work if it were not a system of PDE rather than a single PDE, but recall my $u$ is vector-valued.